# The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-writing

[image]

How do I show this in a convincing manner? I know I need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but I find it difficult to show any steps in between, as it appears obvious?

Comment: See [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle -x = \int_1^y \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}dt$

By FTC,

$\displaystyle -\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}$

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$